After renaming file in Android studio it is deleting from git (and lost history)
For some reason, when I rename a file in Android Studio through the "refactor -> rename..." menu, the file is displayed in Git as new and the old file is deleted. Here's an example:
There is a file Utils, I renamed it to LauncherIntentHelper
In this case, Utils is marked as deleted and LauncherIntentHelper as newly added, so git history for Utils are lost.
I can’t understand why this happens and it seems that earlier when renaming a file through the Android Studio UI, the renaming in Git was displayed correctly.
Btw, I'm not using remote repository, currently this local repository (so all commits don't pushed, only commited).
I'm using Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 RC 2  which is currently in Beta channel
UPDATE:
It's really strange, but even when I do this using the git command line (git mv D:\Work*\launcher\Utils.kt D:\Work*\launcher\LauncherIntentHelper.kt) and modify the file at the same time, it is still marked as new after the commit (the old one is deleted). When I did this in two commits, renaming in the first and changing the content in the second, and then merging them with amend, the effect was the same. To properly rename the file and then change its content, I had to make two separate commits.
And it's doubly strange because earlier renaming through the Android Studio interface worked correctly with git (without the need to manually use the command line).

You must rename git files with git mv or you will lose your whole history :-)
Demo
#!/bin/bash

# Clone the original repo
cd        /tmp
rm -rf    /tmp/local-repo
git init  /tmp/local-repo

# Switch to the new repo
cd /tmp/local-repo

# Add some dummy content
echo "a" > a.txt
echo "b" > b.txt

# Commit the changes
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

# View current permissions
echo -e "----------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "$ mv a.txt A.txt"
echo -e "$ git mv b.txt B.txt"
echo -e ""
mv a.txt A1.txt
git mv b.txt B1.txt
git status

Output:
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/local-repo/.git/
[main (root-commit) a45ab66] Initial commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
 create mode 100644 b.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------
$ mv a.txt A.txt
$ git mv b.txt B.txt

On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        renamed:    b.txt -> B1.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    a.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        A1.txt


Thanks, I was trying to do same steps. I've updated my question to provide more details about mentioned solution.
